# When working with Ajax how do you get output from the script on the server recieving the request?

Tags: php, ajax, testing

For example a client's web browser executes the JavaScript

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "LatestFashion.php", true)
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xmlhttp.send("name="+encodeURIComponent(name.value)+"&gender="+encodeURIComponent(gender.value))
```

The page LatestFashion.php does a bunch of work but it's driving me nuts trouble shooting it. How can I output content to the screen or some reasonable source so I can know what value variables are holding in LatestFashion.php? This wouldn't exist in a production release. The only thing I can think of is opening a file and writing to it. Right now LatestFashion.php isn't working and trouble shooting is pretty damn hard. A query against the database is run and I can't see what results it actually gets. Right now I've tried independently running the SQL query with manually adding in the data given to the script by `name` and `gender`.

EDIT: I'm using FireFox.

Comment: You can use curl. See http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: @BenLee How would making command line requests help?

Comment: You can use curl to make a POST request to LatestFashion.php, output the results to a file, and view the file in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome or Safari (and I'm sure Firefox has it as well), you can use the "Network" tab of the web inspector to view the response from your AJAX request to that file. So in the file you can output some debug stuff and that will show up in the details for that call in the Network tab.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I'm using FireFox. Could you explain more as to how I would output debug stuff from the PHP file that gets called with Ajax?

Comment: Just put var_dump or echo out variables in the PHP file. If you're using JSON it would create malformed JSON and mess up whatever is supposed to happen after the AJAX call, but at least you will be able to see what's happening with your variables.

Comment: That's the problem whatever I echo from the PHP wont actually display in the browser, not unless I use Ajax to send it back to the browser and update the page dynamically.

Comment: Which is exactly why you should use the network tab to view the raw output

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- check php errors log
- show results of the request in the developper tools of the browser (in Chrome, network tab, click on the request to see what has been posted and the related response, add visual debugging stuff if it helps you)
- use a log file. For example if you want to see what the PHP script received, you can do :  `file_put_contents ('mylog.txt', print_r($_REQUEST,true), FILE_APPEND);`

Finally, a simple way is to use GET instead of POST so you can easily call your script with parameters directly in the browser and see results. When OK you switch back to POST if needed.